# How to reserve more than one column for a function output?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am using TA-Lib library to calculate Bollinger Band for stock data: `upperband, middleband, lowerband = BBANDS(close, timeperiod=5, nbdevup=2, nbdevdn=2, matype=0)`

My code is `df['Bollinger Bands'] = talib.BBANDS(cl, timeperiod=5, nbdevup=2, nbdevdn=2, matype=0)` but python gives out an error "Length of values does not match length of index"??

Possibly, it could be due to three outputs that BBands produce "upperband, middleband, lowerband" that my code is trying to pushing into one. Is there some way to provide three columns for the output?

Comment: df['Bollinger Bands'], df['Column1'], df['Column2'] = talib.BBANDS(cl, t.....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['BB_upperband'], df['BB_middleband'], df['BB_lowerband'] = talib.BBANDS(cl, timeperiod=5, nbdevup=2, nbdevdn=2, matype=0)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.